# How to pray qaza of qasr prayer?

Tags: salat, salat-al-qasr

On my way back to home while traveling, I missed asr prayer. Now I am at home and praying full prayers. How should I pray qaza of my asr prayer, two rakats or four? When `Magrib` time started, I was in travel.

Options are

- Since, I am not traveling,  I should pray full for asr.
- Since, I missed two rakats of asr, I should pray two rakats.

Both point of view seems valid to me. Not that it matters much (its only two rakats), but is there any guidance available in Quran or hadith ?

Answer (score 2):

Well  the question is: Have you been traveling at 'Asr time if so and you didn't reach your home before maghrib time you have to do qaza' for 2 raka'a as you had the right to pray qasr!

If you haven't been traveling (having the status of a musafir) at 'Asr time of course you should do the full 4 raka'a.

And once you arrive at home you should also see if you can catch up maghrib etc.

If you pray qaza' you pray the same length or number of raka'at you should have done the prayer if you did it at time. qaza' is just repeating prayer 1:1 as if it was at time! So you must consider your status!

Acoording to these 2 fatwas [1](http://www.al-eman.com/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%88%D9%89/%D9%82%D8%B6%D8%A7%D8%A1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A9%20%D9%81%D9%89%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%81%D8%B1/i8658&rs&p7) [2](http://www.al-islam.com/Content.aspx?pageid=1135&ContentID=1588) this is the opinion of the Maliki and Hanafi Madhab while Shafi'i and Hanbali (this is quoted in the following [fatwa](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/179453)) say if you returned to your place (home) you will have to do qada' (qaza) for 4 raka'a prayer as usual no matter if it was a qaza' for qasr or not!

And Allah knows best!

Comment: An extra bonus on Keeping Track of Qaza namaz http://bit.ly/KazaSalat

Answer (score -1):

If you reach home, you are no more in a traveller status and should offer the complete prayer.

The Qasr option facilitates the traveller with a shortened prayer to complete the salah on time and not to keep this pending until he reaches home to avail the Qasr prayer.

Allah Knows the best. 
May Allah guide and show us the right path. Aameen.

Answer (score -3):

Responding to your question has two answers by two options

1. If you were traveling and you heard the `magrib` adhan in your car, you have to read your qaza salat by 2 rak'ats.
2. If you were travelling and you heard maqrib adhan in your city or at the city gate you have to read your qaza by 4 rak'ats.

Comment: Is it your opinion or someone else? If someone else has that opinion, please provide reference for it